# Golang get command tty output

Tags: go, exec, tty

I'm using go's exec Run command to get command output, which works great when the command 'Stdout' field is set to `os.Stdout`, and the error is sent to `os.Stderr`.

I want to display the output and the error output to the console, but I also want my program to see what the output was.

I then made my own Writer type that did just that, wrote both to a buffer and printed to the terminal.

Here's the problem—some applications change their output to something much less readable by humans when it detects it's not writing to a tty. So the output I get changes to something ugly when I do it in the latter way. (cleaner for computers, uglier for humans)

I wanted to know if there was some way within Go to convince whatever command I'm running that I am a tty, despite not being `os.Stdout/os.Stderr`. I know it's possible to do using the `script` bash command, but that uses a different flag depending on Darwin/Linux, so I'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only practical way to solve this is to allocate a [pseudo terminal (PTY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) and make your external process use it for its output: since PTY is still a terminal, a process checking whether it's connected to a real terminal thinks it is.

You may start with [this query](https://godoc.org/?q=pty).

The `github.com/creack/pty`is probably a good starting point.

The next step is to have a package implementing a PTY actually allocate it, and connect "the other end" of a PTY to your custom writer.

(By the way, there's no point in writing a custom "multi writer" as there exist [`io.MultiWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter)).