# How do I make processes think output is to a terminal?

Tags: go, unix, process

I'm writing a Go program that pipes command output (which the user enters) through another command (`lolcat`). However, when I use this program to run `vim`, it complains that the output is not to a terminal:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

Other programs are also able to detect that output is being piped. Is there a way to fool all processes into thinking that they're outputting to a terminal?

Is it possible that code similar to this section of code could help: https://github.com/cipriancraciun/z-run/blob/master/sources/lib/input.go#L52-L58? (this isn't my repo)

Here's the relevant piece of code I'm using right now: https://github.com/quackduck/lolsh/blob/main/lolsh.go#L209-L263

Comment: Even if you managed to fool vim in this way, how would it be able render itself if not to a terminal? An interactive editor UI can't be represented as a pipe. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033273/720999). But @Thomas is correct: Vim is a so-called full-screen terminal application—that is, it assumes it has a screen of C×L characters which is can fully control through sending the underlying terminal device special control sequences, so unless you somehow connect an "interpreter" of such sequences to the other end of your PTY link, I'm not sure how it's going to work.

Comment: @Thomas it does render itself through lolcat. `vim` doesn't know that output is in the end to a terminal.

Comment: You could use a pseudo-terminal. Search for "pseudo-terminal" or "pseudoterminal" or "pty" in combination with "golang" and check the available libraries or code examples, e.g. https://github.com/creack/pty, https://github.com/google/goterm, https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/internal/pty/